# Calculate Percentage with QUERY on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets database like this:

```
   Name  | Value  | Answer
     A   |  100   |   Y
     B   |  200   |   N
     C   |  10    |   Y
     A   |  100   |   N
     A   |  1000  |   Y
     B   |  50    |   Y
     B   |  200   |   N
```

And I want, by using `QUERY`, to get the total percentage of "Answer" like this:

```
Answer | %Total 
  Y    |  57%  
  N    |  42%
```

And the percentage of Y and N per name:

```
Name | Sum  | Count |  %Y  | %N  
A    | 1200 |   3   | 28%  | 71% 
B    |  450 |   3   | 14%  | 85%    
C    |  10  |   1   | 14%  | 85%
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:C8;"SELECT A, SUM(B), COUNT(B) group by A")
```

I got the `SUM` and the `COUNT`, but couldn't figure how to get the percentage as cited above.
Could somebody with more experience please help with that?

Comment: I think google QUERY alone isn't capable of doing what you are trying to do. For the first percentage, you can try to use =query(A1:C8,"select C, count(C) group by C") and then apply a formula to calculate %s.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Oren, I'm not sure if it's possible to do it using just QUERY indeed. Your idea works well, I think I'll do something this way.

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily achieved with a sub query in SQL but it seems that Google Sheets doesn't support it. Instead, you can add a calculated number of total records in the query.

```
=QUERY(D:D, "SELECT D, COUNT(D)/"&COUNTA(D:D)-1&" WHERE D IS NOT NULL GROUP BY D", 1)
```